# Min index built-in function

Tags: python

Python has a built-in function `min` which returns the minimum value within an `iterable`.

This is very useful to make your code short and clear. However, many times I find myself implementing my own `minIndex` function:

```
def minIndex(v):
    ret = -1
    for i in xrange(len(v)):
        if ret < 0 or v[ret]>v[i]:
            ret = i
    return ret
```

Does Python provide a `minIndex` built-in implementation?

Comment: there is a [`numpy.argmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily use `min()` for this:

```
min(range(len(v)), key=v.__getitem__)
```

This produces a sequence of indices (in Python 2, `xrange()` would do too), then maps those indices to values in `v` to determine the minimum.

Demo:

```
>>> v = [42, 81, 7, 99, -1, 1991]
>>> min(range(len(v)), key=v.__getitem__)
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do this, if you don't like using `__getitem__`

```
min(range(len(v)),key=lambda x : v[x])
```